# Is there an R function to match dataframe columns based on string with partial similarity?

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I am trying to match columns of two dataframes in R based on a partially corresponding string. Below you will find a small example of what my dataframes look like. Dataframe 1 contains stimulus strings that match to strings in dataframe 2, with "_FAM" behind it.

Dataframe 1:

```
Stimulus     Mean
CR00         0.333
CR01         0.972
DF_0_30      0.831
DF_6_40      0.327
```

Dataframe 2:

```
Stimulus     Mean
DF_0_30_FAM  0.423
CR00_FAM     0.768
DF_6_40_FAM  0.672
CR01_FAM     0.012
```

Is there a tool to match this? In the end I would like to create 1 dataframe that contains all matching strings, so I can calculate a correlation between the two means.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look into `agrep`?

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this if you only have the pattern `_FAM` that is added in the second dataframe :

```
df2[,"Stimulus"]=str_remove(df2[,"Stimulus"],"_FAM")
merge(df1,df2,by="Stimulus")
```

First you remove the pattern `_FAM` and after you can directly merge your datasets

Comment: Thanks for helping! I have tried this, however it gives me the following result after the first line: 

Stimulus (row 1): c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, ....)


Warning message:
In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

And then when executing the second line: 

> merge(stim_data,Famsubset2,by="stimulus")
[1] stimulus  Mean.x    Std.x     stim_char avg_fam   Mean.y    Std.y    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).

Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: This is hard to tell you what is happening here without an overview of your own dataframes. If you add the output of `dput(head(stim_data))` and `dput(head(Famsubset2))`to your post I would be glad to help